# android application works fine in 2.3.3 but stops working after some hours in 4.1.2

Tags: android, service

My application is a tracking application that gets location at every 2 min and send to server. this work is done using a service which is repetedly started by AlarmManager at every 2 min It works fine in android 2.3.3. It also works fine in 4.1.2 for some time then it stops. without any error message like. forced close ,not responding etc.

Comment: Please post your logcat error.

Comment: Any process is work in backgound ?

Comment: yes. application uses android service so it works in background only

Comment: where can I get the logcat in mobile phone

Comment: The service has the methods onDestroy() and onLowMemory()/onTrimMemory(). I'd suggest making them output something into the log, so that you would see if they are called.

Comment: where to dispay logs in mobile phone? Do i need to create any text file for that?

Comment: Please use `adb logcat`. If you are using Windows, consider changing the screen buffer width to about 140 and the height to about 300-800 (you will see scrollbars) and setting a smaller font. One more option is to redirect output to a file and use the Far Manager built-in viewer to view the file. Under linux, copying and pasting the logcat output is a bit easier.

Comment: Eclipse has a tab for logcat, but that tab is a listview and is not as good as plain text.

Comment: actually i cannot test the app in emulator as it requires GPS i have to  install it in mobile phone and then check